# Changing lead owner via Dynamics Web API

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm

I'm working according to the examples at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607875.aspx

I'm able to update other single-value navigation properties with PATCH, i.e.

```
PATCH [DYNAMICS_URL]/api/data/v8.1.0.538/leads(355c33b0-88fe-e611-80f1-c4346bad60a8)

{
  "campaignid@odata.bind":"[DYNAMICS_URL]/api/data/v8.1.0.538/campaigns(fdfa106a-5dd1-e511-80df-3863bb349bd8)",
}
```

However, trying to run the same for changing owner id

```
PATCH [DYNAMICS_URL]/api/data/v8.1.0.538/leads(355c33b0-88fe-e611-80f1-c4346bad60a8)

{
  "ownerid@odata.bind":"[DYNAMICS_URL]/api/data/v8.1.0.538/systemusers(4bf3d2d8-f2ec-e511-80d5-5065f38b15d1)"
}
```

gives 500 internal server error for

```
"message": "email With Id = 1a70458b-92fe-e611-80f1-c4346bad60a8 Does Not Exist"
```

What's going on? Assigning the lead owner via the CRM web app works fine.

Furthermore, trying to update `owninguser` the same way gives `204 No content` but doesn't seem to update anything.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the owner of the record is not an Update operation. This is Assign operation, and unfortunately there is no possibility to assign record using REST request. But you can use SOAP for doing this:

```
function AssignRecord(Assignee, Target, entityName) {
var request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
request += "<s:Body>";
request += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\"";
request += " xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
request += "<request i:type=\"b:AssignRequest\"";
request += " xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\"";
request += " xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
request += "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
request += "<c:key>Target</c:key>";
request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
request += "<a:Id>" + Target + "</a:Id>";
request += "<a:LogicalName>" + entityName + "</a:LogicalName>";
request += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
request += "</c:value>";
request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
request += "<c:key>Assignee</c:key>";
request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
request += "<a:Id>" + Assignee + "</a:Id>";
request += "<a:LogicalName>systemuser</a:LogicalName>";
request += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
request += "</c:value>";
request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
request += "</a:Parameters>";
request += "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
request += "<a:RequestName>Assign</a:RequestName>";
request += "</request>";
request += "</Execute>";
request += "</s:Body>";
request += "</s:Envelope>";
// Get server URL

var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("POST", serverUrl, true)

// Responses will return XML. It isn’t possible to return JSON.

req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");

req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute&#8221");

req.onreadystatechange = function () { if (req.readyState == 4) {

    if (req.status === 200) {

        alert("Success !!!");

    }

    else {

        alert("Error – " + req.responseXML);

    }

}

};
req.send(request); }
```